# Undefined pcntl_signal_dispatch() with pcntl installed

Tags: php, ubuntu-server, pcntl

I'm having touble using `pcntl` on an ubuntu server VM.
I have a PHP script making threads to do repetitive stuff.
My server has the pcntl extention for PHP.

Using command `php -me` output this :

> calendar
>   ctype
>   curl
>   date
>   dom
>   filter
>   hash
>   iconv
>   json
>   libxml
>   mbstring
>   mysql
>   pcntl
>   pcre
>   PDO
>   pdo_mysql
>   pdo_sqlite
>   posix
>   Reflection
>   session
>   shmop
>   SimpleXML
>   SPL
>   SQLite
>   standard
>   tokenizer
>   xml
>   xmlreader
>   xmlwriter
>   zip
>   zlib

I added logs in the code so I'm sure `pcntl_fork`, `pcntl_wait` and `pcntl_wexitstatus` are executed by the script.
But on the line using `pcntl_signal_dispatch()`, it crashed with the error :

> Call to undefined function pcntl_signal_dispatch()

Any clue is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike most (if not all) of the PCNTL functions,`pcntl_signal_dispatch()` requires PHP 5.3 or newer: http://php.net/pcntl_signal_dispatch

So you're either running a really old PHP version, or the function is disabled in php.ini, but my guess would be the former.

Comment: Oh god, indeed server's PHP version is `PHP 5.2.10`. Is there an way to make it work on older PHP ? (an other function that does the same job, some code to write...). We can't update PHP because of regression risks...

Comment: No, I don't think so. And you really shouldn't ... regression risks might've been an excuse while PHP 5.2 was still officially supported, but that hasn't been the case for more than 4 years now. And regressions can be tested for ... you can prepare for that.

Comment: Actually, there are 2 solutions : using `declare(ticks=1)` keeping the current PHP version (5.2.10), or upgrade to PHP 5.3 in order to use `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` (unfortunately, only the client can decide, after listening to my opinion). Thanks !